# Yammer pic not updated even after 24 hours. How to update the pic using rest API

Tags: office365api, yammer, sharepoint-online, o365rwsclient

I have tried uploading the profile picture through yammer API. But it is not updated even after 2 days. When I checked through rest API, the attribute for picture is empty.

```
<mugshot-url>https://mug0.assets-yammer.com/mugshot/images/48x48/no_photo.png</mugshot-url>
<mugshot-url-template>https://mug0.assets-yammer.com/mugshot/images/{width}x{height}/no_photo.png</mugshot-url-template>
```

please suggest. How much time does it usually takes to propagate the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like i was navigating to o365 profile picture for updating. we have to navigate to below location. (Tested)

https://www.yammer.com/mdlz.com/#/account/profile_info?from=nav